# CSS display: none; href

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-freetime">

            <li class="active">
                <a class="btn-nav-tab" href="#mod2" data-toggle="tab">Bar El Gordo</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="btn-nav-tab" href="#mod3" data-toggle="tab">'La Tabernilla'</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="btn-nav-tab" href="#mod4" data-toggle="tab">Restaurante La Muralla</a>
            </li>
```

i tried to use

```
.nav .btn-nav-tab{ display: none; }
```

but it hides everything and I want it to only hide mod1.
I try to

```
a[href="#mod1"]{ display: none; }
```

but didnt work

Comment: please format your question properly... and `a[href="#mod1]` will work, but you don't have "mod1" in your html...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, you could use either `nth-child` ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)) or `last-child` ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child))

```
.nav li:last-child {display: none}
```

or

```
.nav li:nth-child(3) {display: none}
```

Comment: edit: somehow I misread the question, and thought you were trying to hide #mod4. not sure how I managed to think that. @kukkuz's comment is correct: targeting `a[href="..."]` is the right way to go…… you just need an `id="mod1"` to target

Answer (score 0):

You should use ids instead of href attributes for what you want to do as it is more accurate and will work on any version of CSS and any browser.

Your updated html

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-freetime">

<li class="active">
    <a id="mod2" class="btn-nav-tab" href="#mod2" data-toggle="tab">Bar El Gordo</a>
</li>

<li>
    <a id="mod3" class="btn-nav-tab" href="#mod3" data-toggle="tab">'La Tabernilla'</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="mod4" class="btn-nav-tab" href="#mod4" data-toggle="tab">Restaurante La Muralla</a>
</li>
```

Your updated css

```
#mod3 { display: block; } // can replace with any mod id

.nav .btn-nav-tab{ display: none; }
```

You can replace #mod3 with any id as long as it is in your html.